# Help in configuring .htaccess to exclude a path from rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a root folder with the following .htaccess configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

What I need is, I have installed a wordpress site in a sub directory `'blog/'`. Now I am able to access the home page of the blog since I have givien `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. But clicking on a post will redirect me to the index file in root folder. How can I solve this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a RewriteCond to exclude paths which begin with "blog/"
Something like (added some existant rule for context)

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?blog/
```

Not tested, but you get the idea